# Geometric effect image manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry

I'm trying to build a website allowing users to upload a photo of their face and then return a stylized output such as this example :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeqIC.jpg]

I'm not a graphics expert by any means so I'm not sure of the correct term to describe this image manipulation effect.

I have looked at a few `JavaScript image libraries (Fabric, Pixastic)` but they only seem to offer a fairly basic Pixelation effect which is not quite what I am looking for.

If anyone can point me in the right direction of a suitable JavaScript library I would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would need to implement:

- [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)
- [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)

These are relatively complex areas in the field of polygons and the combination ([Voroni/Delaunay tesselation](http://www.unc.edu/~ivaisman/delaunay/tessell.htm)) represent a very specific usage (as the effect in the image). You can probably get away with just the triangulation though, but there are libraries out there that can help you with the basics and from there you may be able to apply it to images and the color values.

Here are a couple of projects to start you off:

- https://github.com/ironwallaby/delaunay
- https://code.google.com/p/javascript-voronoi/

Comment: Paper.js has a Voroni example on its Website http://paperjs.org/examples/voronoi/

Comment: Constructing a Delaunay triangulation is not the whole story. In the first place, the vertices must be chosen in a way that will result in roughly homogenous areas. Actually, this is an image segmentation problem. I would take a look at this paper: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4517766&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F4505270%2F4517521%2F04517766.pdf%3Farnumber%3D4517766; also http://i.cs.hku.hk/~yzyu/publication/imgseg.pdf